# Get the value of Buttonfield in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonfield

Say I have only two columns in my GridView *(ID & Name)* and I need to get the value of ID whenever I click on it. For example, if I click on *123*, I should get *123*. But here... that's not the case... when I click on any ID it returns the name beside that ID right (*eg; in case of 123, I get Tony Stark*), but when I get the value of ID on click, it always returns me an empty string.

In other words, I get the name in id right (when X=1), but when X=0, id becomes an empty string... ***(int X and string id : see C# code below)***

[image: sample GridView1]

**XAML Code in my GridView:**

```
                        <asp:ButtonField
                            DataTextField="ID"
                            HeaderText="ID">
                        </asp:ButtonField>

                        <asp:BoundField
                            DataField="Name"
                            HeaderText="NAME">
                        </asp:BoundField>
```

**C#:**

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[X].Text.ToString();
        Response.Write(id);
    }
```

What's going wrong?!! And how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What is X supposed to be?

Comment: X is the index for cells (see C# code). It's 1 for Name column, and should be 0 for ID column, but that's not the case. Having 0 always gives me an empty string.

Comment: Generally speaking with .net grids, the Cell will have another control inside it. If you check Cells[0].Controls or .Children while debugging, are there any instances of this?  Also, are you sure you have the correct row index?

Comment: Yes the row is correct, so is the cell. I get this output when I try string id = EmployeeList.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[0].Controls.ToString(); "System.Web.UI.ControlCollection"

Comment: What is the type of EmployeeList.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[0].Controls[0]

Answer (score 2):

The more complex but better solution is:

In GridView, use DataKeyNames tag and RowCommand event and put the bind value in DataKeyName, example:

```
DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

Use a Template Field in your gridview (you do not need use only imagebutton like as example below):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="GridViewOpc">
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="buttonDelete" runat="server" Width="17" Height="17" AlternateText="Update"
                                            CausesValidation="False" Visible="false" CommandName="Delete" Enabled="true"
                                            ImageUrl="~/yourDeletepicture.gif"  />

                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="buttonUpdate" runat="server" AlternateText="Update" Width="17"
                                            Height="17" CausesValidation="False" Visible="false" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/yourUpdatePicture.gif" />
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And get it on CodeBehind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

            Control ctl = e.CommandSource as Control;
            GridViewRow CurrentRow = ctl.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

                if (e.CommandName == "Update")
                {

                    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[CurrentRow.RowIndex][0]);
                }

               if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
                {

                    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[CurrentRow.RowIndex][0]);

                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `templateField` you can also get the value from `ButtonField`.
In your `ButtonField` you need to give it a `ButtonType`.

XML:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="PanelName" DataTextField="PANEL_NAME" HeaderText="Panel Name" runat="server" SortExpression="PANEL_NAME" text="PanleName"/>
```

Code:

```
if (e.CommandName == "PanelName")
{
    string PanleName;
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow selectedRow = dgSearchResult.Rows[index];
    PanleName = ((LinkButton)selectedRow.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
}
```

Note: Whatever your cell index is, Cells[1] means index is 1. But Controls always start from 0 if only one control is in your GridView.

Answer (score -1):

In your RowCommand handler, I THINK this is what you want:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int id = (int)(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID"));
        Response.Write(id);
    }
}
```

I'm converting from vb, so I may have missed some syntax, but you get the idea...